# Cmake 3.17 can't run bootstrap because **fatal error: config.h: No such file or directory**

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, cmake

**Please note:** I'm using the WSL Ubuntu app on Win10.

I downloaded the CMake 3.17.1 Linux/Unix Source from [CMake.org | Downloads](http://cmake.org/downloads) and followed the instructions on [CMake.org | Install](http://cmake.org/install). I ran the `./bootstrap` command from the WSL Ubuntu App and encountered the following error:

```
CMake 3.17.1, Copyright 2000-2020 Kitware, Inc. and Contributors
Found GNU toolchain
C compiler on this system is: gcc
C++ compiler on this system is: g++
Makefile processor on this system is: make
g++ has setenv
g++ has unsetenv
g++ does not have environ in stdlib.h
g++ has stl wstring
g++ has <ext/stdio_filebuf.h>
---------------------------------------------
g++        -DCMAKE_BOOTSTRAP    -DCMake_HAVE_CXX_MAKE_UNIQUE=1   -I/mnt/d/cmake/cmake-3.17.1/Bootstrap.cmk   -I/mnt/d/cmake/cmake-3.17.1/Source   -I/mnt/d/cmake/cmake-3.17.1/Source/LexerParser   -I/mnt/d/cmake/cmake-3.17.1/Utilities/std   -I/mnt/d/cmake/cmake-3.17.1/Utilities  -c /mnt/d/cmake/cmake-3.17.1/Source/cmMakefile.cxx -o cmMakefile.o
In file included from /mnt/d/cmake/cmake-3.17.1/Utilities/cmjsoncpp/include/json/value.h:10:0,
                 from /mnt/d/cmake/cmake-3.17.1/Utilities/cm_jsoncpp_value.h:11,
                 from /mnt/d/cmake/cmake-3.17.1/Source/cmMakefile.cxx:25:
/mnt/d/cmake/cmake-3.17.1/Utilities/cmjsoncpp/include/json/forwards.h:10:10: fatal error: config.h: No such file or directory
 #include "config.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
Makefile:268: recipe for target 'cmMakefile.o' failed
make: *** [cmMakefile.o] Error 1
---------------------------------------------
Error when bootstrapping CMake:
Problem while running make
```

I don't understand how this can be missing as I downloaded it from the official distributor... Is there a way to fix this?

Additional info:

```
g++ --version  
g++ (Ubuntu 9.3.0-11ubuntu0~18.04.1) 9.3.0

gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 9.3.0-11ubuntu0~18.04.1) 9.3.0
```

Comment: It might be a better idea not to use mounted host OS drives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Daniel B's comment, I downloaded it via the Ubuntu terminal again using wget and the download link, unpacked it and then followed the install instructions again. That worked.